# How to get IWICDevelopRaw interface

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d, wic

I am rendering a raw photo (sony .arw) using WIC and Direct2D. This part I have working it loads and I can draw it on the screen. What I want to do is get access to the IWICDevelopRaw interface. I assumed that the decoder would implement that interface so I tried:

```
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> pDecoder;

    HRESULT hr = m_pWICIMagingFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
        uri,
        NULL,
        GENERIC_READ,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
        &pDecoder
        );
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IUnknown> u;
        hr = pDecoder.AsIID(IID_IWICDevelopRaw, &u);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) { 
            ...

        }
    }
```

But `hr` is `NO_INTERFACE` after the call `to pDecoder.AsIID(IID_IWICDevelopRaw, &u)`

Comment: The interface exposes properties of the image.  So you'll have to get it from the actual bitmap object, not the decoder.  Looks like IWICBitmapSource => IWICBitmapFrameDecode => IWICDevelopRaw.

Comment: Thank you it is indeed an interface of the frame.